# Change LoopBack default error object

Tags: node.js, loopback

In LoopBack, when a required parameter of an API is missed, it will return some errors like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 400,
        "name": "Error",
        "message": "fields is a required argument"
    }
}
```

But what I want is an error like this:

```
{
    "response status": 400,
    "response body": {
        "message": "fields is a required argument"
    }
}
```

How should I change the default error structure in LoopBack?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
  YourModel.observe('before save', function(context, next) {
    if (context.error) {
      // get values from error object that you want, could be on context.error.code
      var newError = new Error("fields is a required argument");
      newError.status = 400;
      next(error);
    }
    //handle other cases
  });
```

Instead of the string, you can of course pass an object if that's whats you are looking for. Hope this helps

Comment: 'Before save' is when you want to save an instance in the database. But my problem is when an API is called and the required parameter is missed.